# Javascript .click function switch/case issue

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, contextmenu, case

Can anyone help me understand why I'm not receiving the alerts on my switch case?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VW64Z/)

```
$(".system-menu li").click(function(){

switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {

    case "Info": 
    alert("Info");
    break;

    case "Contact": 
    alert("Contact");
    break;

    case "Help": 
    alert("Help"); 
    break;
}
```

});

I'm trying to trigger events for each different case but maybe there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Try to stop event propagation, as you have an event on the document, that triggers first. Or check for your elements on the document event. If you remove that, it works http://jsfiddle.net/VW64Z/2/

Comment: My issues were resolved after bringing the code into my page vs referencing an outside js file. Thanks for your help.